# How do I change my tor IP?

Tags: osx, init.d, tor

I have been trying to restart tor (for the sole purpose of changing my IP address).

So what I did was make an alias to `pkill -x tor; tor`. But that gives me the usual tor is already in use/the ip address is already in use etc. indicating that I tried to start tor when it was already running.

I figured that the `;` was at fault, because that doesn't care if the process has been killed or not so instead I used `&&`. But that did the same thing, first start tor, then kill it.

So I looked it up, and some people use something like `sudo /usr/local/etc/init.d/tor`, but the way I start it is by simply running the tor executable, and when I tried to do the `init.d` thing it just told me that the command doesn't exist (which is logical because it doesn't).

So what am I supposed to do?

Also, I have no `init.d` folder I also have no `systemd`.

Comment: I don't have tor on linux, however on windows you can renew your indentity (that is get a new adress), is there no such button on tor for linux ?

Comment: try `pkill -x tor ; sleep 30 ; tor` . this should give some time for tor to stop before restarting.

Comment: @Archemar (Im using OS X) But I'm not talking a GUI this is pure command line tor, not TorBrowser.

Answer (score 4):

My answer is quoted from [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16987518/how-to-request-new-tor-identity-in-terminal)

> The fastest and easiest way to get "new identity" is send HUP signal.
>
> Tor daemon re-read configurations files and make "new identity".
>
> I keep special bash script for this:

```
# cat /usr/local/bin/nym 
#!/bin/bash
pidof tor | xargs sudo kill -HUP
```

> My sudoers file full of NOPASSWD:

```
# cat /etc/sudoers 
....
anonymous       ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
...
```

Comment: Wouldn't `sudo kill -HUP $(pidof tor)` be slightly better? Less processes, etc.